# integrating DPDK with OVS

Tags: openvswitch, dpdk

I have a question about integrating `DPDK` with `OVS`. Since `DPDK` will help packet bypass kernel and pass packet to user-space directly for application, does it make sense to integrate `DPDK` with `OVS` if I just want to boost the basic packet switching of a Linux machine?

```
A (192.168.1.1) -> B (DPDK-OVS) -> C (192.168.1.2)
```

Comment: Such integration has been done. Look for end-to-end instructions for redhat/centos here: https://people.redhat.com/~pmatilai/dpdk-guide/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a basic packet switching, then there is no need to work with OvS because their performance benchmark are almost the same according to [1], but when you decide to use OVS then you need to understand how to handle ovs-vswitchd deamon to configure data-plain by using flow tables etc.. My suggestion is that please just have a look at L3 forwarding examples for DPDK, because it is clear and it will be enough in your case.

[1] http://www.opendataplane.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/SFO15-408-ODP-DPDK-platform-performance.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use OVS, consider using OVS with DPDK.

Several components and datapath of OVS were enhanced using DPDK packet processing libraries.

Depending on your use-case, you will notice higher network throughput and reduced latency. Please refer to ["Using Open vSwitch* with DPDK for Inter-VM NFV Applications"](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-open-vswitch-with-dpdk-for-inter-vm-nfv-applications) for a sample use-case.